# Conditional Queryover depending on the context

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I want to do a `QueryOver` on an object for which I want to do an outer join on its sublist only if the current object has a property set to true.
Let's say you have an object `Store` which has a list of `Product`, and `Product` has a sublist `Phone`
The object `Store` has a boolean property `HasAllProducts`.

If `HasAllProducts` is true, then `Store` doesn't need to know the list of products, so no outer join is needed.
If`HasAllProducts` is false, then `Store` has to know its list of `Product`s so an outer join is needed, and another outer join is needed between Product and Phone

So I would like a query like

```
session.QueryOver<Store>(() => storeAlias)
if (!storeAlias.HasAllProducts)
{
  .Left.JoinAlias(s => s.Products, () => productAlias)
}
.Future<Store>();

//Then again to avoid catersian product
if (!storeAlias.HasAllProducts)
{
session.QueryOver<Product>(() => productAlias)
  .Left.JoinAlias(p => p.Phones, () => phoneAlias)
.Future<Phone>();
}
```

I know that for the first join, you can use withClause, but how would you perform (or not perform) the second conditional join? it should not be executed if no `Phone`is fetched in the previous query.

The problem with with clause is that it will generate a query in all cases, I would like to avoid running two additional queries if it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest 2 queries.

```
var stores = session.QueryOver<Store>()
    .Where(filter)
    .Future();

// only to intialize needed child collections
session.QueryOver<Store>()
    .Where(filter)
    .Where(s => !s.HasAllProducts)
    .JoinQueryOver<Exam>(s => s.Products)
        .Fetch(SelectMode.ChildFetch, e => e.Phones)  // NHibernate 5
        .Fetch(x => x.Phones).Eager  // NHibernate 3
    .Future();
```

Another option is to use CollectionBatchSize to not eager load here but use lazy loading with batches on usage

Comment: Thx, are you sure SelectMode.ChildFetch exists? if you google it, you have only five results, I have nibernate version 3.3.3 and it is not proposed as a SelectMode

Comment: @Ferdossi I'v added the syntax for NHibernate 3 as well. Didn't know which one you were using

Comment: ok, thx but the problem is that it ends up with a cartesian produt, if I have 5 products, each 10 phones, I get 50 products

Comment: @Ferdossi What is the expected result, Stores with Products and Phones initialized or one collection of stores and another collection of phones present in products of stores with `!s.HasAllProducts`?